# List of elements keeps using the first element after I nest findelement

Tags: java, selenium

As you can see below I get all the rows in a list. Then when iterating through the rows list I pull out web elements from each row. However when I pull out the web element I keep getting the first web element in the list.

```
System.out.println(row.getText()); //Prints correct values
System.out.println(actualFirstName.getText() + " " + actualLastName.getText()); //Prints incorrect values
```

The code:

```
private WebElement getElementRow(WebDriver driver, String expectedFirstName, String expectedLastName) throws Exception{
    List<WebElement> allRows = getAllRows(driver);
    WebElement actualFirstName;
    WebElement actualLastName;
    for(int i=0; i<allRows.size(); i++){
        WebElement row = allRows.get(i);
        System.out.println(row.getText());
        actualFirstName = row.findElement(firstNameLocator);
        actualLastName = row.findElement(lastNameLocator);
        System.out.println(actualFirstName.getText() + " " + actualLastName.getText());
        if(actualFirstName.getText().equals(expectedFirstName)) && actualLastName.getText().equals(expectedLastName)){
            return row;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception(expectedFirstName + " " + expectedLastName + "  row not found in the list");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here. You say iteration always gives you always the first element in list but then you say your print statement gives you the information that correct row is being referenced. Also what are the values 'firstNameLocator' and 'lastNameLocator' that you are using in findElement method. They seem to be static values from class that are not being passed as parameters to method. They never change inside the method so actualFirstname and actualLastName would never change.

Comment: Take a look at your `firstNameLocator` and `lastNameLocator`. it is possible that they may be referencing the elements from the first row every time.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the HTML and what the two locators are?

Comment: Thank you @Jason you were indeed correct. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my By locators further I realized that my xpath had it referencing the first element

I had

```
private By brokerFirstNameLocator = By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'first-name')]");
private By brokerLastNameLocator = By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'last-name')]");
```

Where I should have had

```
private By firstNameLocator = By.xpath("./div[contains(@id,'first-name')]"); 
private By lastNameLocator = By.xpath("./div[contains(@id,'last-name')]");
```

TBH I was surprised this my intial way didn't work but it is a relative vs absolute path issue